# autoresize iframe not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

**my html code is**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function autoResize(id) 
{
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if (document.getElementById) 
    {
        newheight = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";

}

</script>

<asp:DataList ID="dtlhtml" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <iframe src='<%#Eval("html") %>' width="713" height="250" id="iframe1" frameborder="0" onload="autoResize(this.id);"></iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

**.cs code on page load event**

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("html");
DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["html"] = "";//Any dynamic url path
dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
dtlhtml.DataSource = dt1;
dtlhtml.DataBind();
```

this is not working in local but working fine on online
**Problem**
I am running it online on firefox with version 24.0 is running fine but on my 2 friend pc with same version scrolling is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey my problem is solved as i was giving path as

```
dr["html"] = "http://stackoverflow.com/file/1.html";
```

but the proper way was to give path for calling html page to my iframe was to be

```
dr["html"] ="http://www.stackoverflow.com/file/1.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

your if condition is incorrect, do as below

```
if(document.getElementById(id))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure though, but I guess problem lies here: Numeric value + string might be causing error.

```
document.getElementById(id).height = (newheight) + "px";
document.getElementById(id).width = (newwidth) + "px";
```

You can instead write this as

```
   document.getElementById(id).height = newheight;
    document.getElementById(id).width = newwidth;
```

ALso you can remove 'px' because by default lengths are in pixel only.